# How do I write an mdx expression that counts the occurrences of a fact

Tags: mdx, mondrian

Suppose I have a dimension called library books and a fact called days overdue. How do I write an mdx expression that will return the number of books that exist at each num days overdue value? In other words:

```
Days Overdue | Num books
1            | 3498
2            | 237
3            | 57
```

In SQL, the answer is simple:

```
select days_late,count(*) from days_overdue_fact group by days_late
```

In mdx, I have tried this:

```
with member [Measures].[Overdue Count] as 'count([Book].[System Id].members) '
select  [Measures].[Overdue Count] on 0,
[Measures].[Days Late] on 1
FROM [myCube]
```

But I get a complaint from Mondrian:
'[Measures]' appears in more than one independent axis.

I simply want to group by the fact values.

Comment: You are trying to use MDX like it was SQL. I strongly suggest that you take a step back and take the time to understand how OLAP systems work before trying to write your first queries. There are a ton of tutorials out there available. Do a quick search for "SQL to MDX toturial" and you'll be on the right track.

Comment: " '[Measures]' appears in more than one independent axis. " This error occures because you have [Measures].[Overdue Count] on 0 and
[Measures].[Days Late] on 1.  If you want to retrieve two measures you must put them both on the same axis. I'm not sure I understand what your measure is for Days Overdue.  This is not something you aggregate. My first thought is that you would have a dimension for Days Overdue and your measure is a distinct count of book system IDs from the fact table (to get number of books).

Comment: Thx for the comments. I believe I do understand the difference between mdx and sql and how OLAP systems work. I'm trying to write a specific query here on a special kind of fact (an accumulating snapshot fact, see http://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/11/05/fact-tables/). This query needs to group by a measure value rather than a dimension value, which means I must use sql rather than mdx because mdx just can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to recognize that this overdue measure is simply part of an accumulating snapshot fact (see The Data Warehouse Toolkit, 2n ed., Ralph Kimball or http://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/11/05/fact-tables/), that tracks the status of a book over time as it moves through its checkout/in process.

There's nothing wrong with having an accumulating snapshot fact like this in a cube. You just have to understand what it is and how to query it. In this case I want to count the occurrences of each value that appears in this fact and the easiest way to do that is with a sql group by rather than mdx.

The answer is he sql in the original question. There is no mdx solution for grouping by a measure value that I am aware of. MDX is the wrong tool for this query.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the way you have constructed your cube is wrong. [Days Overdue] doesn't need to (maybe even best not to) be a measure. Measure most frequently is a **DEPENDENT** numeric value which [shall be calculated for each possible combination of dimension values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178239%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). It most definitely **can** take a value of **null** but very scarcely. I don't really see how you relate [Days Overdue] to **ALL** possible combination of dimension values.

What you have here as measure could easily be a calculated dimension field in which you deduct the borrowing date from `NOW()`. There is only one question left to be answered in this case and that's to know if Borrowing date (the date a book is borrowed) belongs to a fact table or not. If that's true then you have to define a new fact dimension and define your relationship there as explained [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167409.aspx).

Comment: I think the days overdue is a legitimate part of an accumulating snapshot fact (as described in Kimball's The Data Warehouse Toolkit). This fact would have the check in and check out dates of a book as it moves through its usual lifecycle, and days overdue would be part of that, just as Kimball describes the states of an order that moves through a retail warehouse.